# jQuery Click Anchor when key is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is what I have right now - it should simulate an anchor click when a user presses the left or right arrow key, but it doesn't - any ideas?

```
    $('body').bind('keydown',function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 39){
            $(".next > a").click();
        }
        else if(e.keyCode == 37){
            $(".back > a").click();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I experienced the same problem. Did you try your selector in the console?

Comment: What does your HTML look like?  Specifically the links that you want to activate.

Answer (score 2):

Triggering the `click` event won't follow the link AFAIK, you need to grab the url and do it manually:

```
location.href = $(".next > a").attr('href');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').bind('keydown',function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 39){
        $(".next > a").get(0).click();
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 37){
        $(".back > a").get(0).click();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('body').bind('keydown',function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 39){
        $(".next > a").trigger('click');
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 37){
        $(".back > a").trigger('click');
    }
});
```

use trigger

Comment: From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/click/), "when .click() is called without arguments, it is a shortcut for .trigger("click")"